# How can I make Opera not open new windows in full screen when it has other windows open in full screen?

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, fullscreen, opera

Here's the behavior I see:

1. have 1 or more windows in Opera open, all in full-screen
2. <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> from app B to Opera
3. <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>
4. Opera opens a new window and immediately full-screens it

I want to be able to <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> a new window and have it not be full-screened. Is this possible?

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? Which _application_ or is it any _application_ does this?

Comment: You can also just press **⌃⌘F** after **⌘N** to take it out of **Full Screen View**.

Comment: hm it does indeed seem to be only Opera. question updated

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: macos big sur 11.5